# How to make ONLY iframe's background transparent (and not foreground)?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe containing a PDF file, that should be shown with a transparent background. So far I've found two ways to do it:

1) I just set the background color to a value that has an opacity of 0.5:

```
<iframe src = "myfile.pdf" allowtransparency="true" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:40px;left:0px;overflow:auto;z-index:5;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);"></iframe>
```

But the background isn't transparent, although I have set a 50% opaque background color:  [Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGeE3.png). If instead I do:

```
background:transparent;
```

Or:

```
background-color:transparent;
```

I get the same result. I still get an opaque background.

2) I can directly set the opacity of the iframe element, and add:

```
opacity:0.5;
```

Inside the style attribute. But this sets ALL the iframe transparency, and not only the background. The result is very ugly: [Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srgUB.png).

How can I make the background transparent while keeping the PDF white page to an opaque color?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
body,
html {
  /*this is just so that this snippet displays correctly*/
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.backdrop {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.backdrop > #pdf {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="backdrop">

  <div id="pdf">
    PDF Content PDF Content PDF Content
    <br>PDF Content PDF Content PDF Content
    <br>PDF Content PDF Content PDF Content
    <br>PDF Content PDF Content PDF Content
    <br>PDF Content PDF Content PDF Content
    <br>PDF Content PDF Content PDF Content
    <br>PDF Content PDF Content PDF Content
    <br>PDF Content PDF Content PDF Content
    <br>PDF Content PDF Content PDF Content
    <br>PDF Content PDF Content PDF Content
    <br>PDF Content PDF Content PDF Content
    <br>

  </div>

</div>

Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br/>Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br>Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br>Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br/>Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br>Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br>Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br/>Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br>Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br>Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br/>Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br>Soem random body text behind the PDF
<br>
```

Comment: Where is the iframe in your solution?